# How to know if there are visible annotations in a map area in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, ios16

i've came here after searching for a while a solution to the problem i have but i couldn't find anything helpfull.

I'm displaying a map in iOS16 using only swiftUI and i'm wondering if its any way to know if the region of the map it's displaying has any annotations or not. I want to display a list in the bottom of the map with the annotations that are visible in that map area, but if the user drag to another position without annotations i want to hide that list.

Many thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SwiftUI design is to generate the view data hierarchy from the model data you need to do this before there are any annotations added to the map. Ie make a state to hold the visible map rect (that you supply and binding to the Map) and using onChange or task(id:) query your database using the new map rect.